# Django: Unbuffered mysql query

Tags: mysql, django

How can I NOT have the full result set from mysql copied into memory in django? I'm itterating over a BIG table which is blowing up my ram when the query copies.

It seems that mysql uses `SSCursor` for this purpose, and I can do all that with the mysql low level interface, but is there a Django way to do it?

Comment: do you need the entire resultSet?  Would minimizing the rows returned by the query work?

Comment: nope, I have to do an operation per row, but I will NEVER revisit any past rows so having them in memory is a waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get 500 items each iteration:

```
count = Model.objects.count()
chunk = 500
for i in range((count/chunk)+1):
    objs = list(Model.objects.all()[i*chunk:(i+1)*chunk])
```

You might also want to have a look at the [QuerySet method iterator()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator).

Comment: Is this as optimal as an unbuffered cursor over the data set? If not, how much worse?

Comment: Afaik What this effectively does is "SELECT stuff FROM table LIMIT <(i+1)*slice> OFFSET <i*slice>." You were worried about your memory usage, this will solve it, because it just keeps a fixed number of rows in memory. The downside is that there are multiple SQL queries, but this shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: The iterator() thingy seems to read the result line by line, so it might be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, the iterator() keeps the whole thing in memory as well sadly